# Creating Objects from JSON

Tags: iphone, ios, json, nsarray

I would like to be able to create an  NSArray or NSDictionary with a JSON string that I receive from a web service. I am using the json framework to do this. The response string will look something along these lines:

```
{count:2,
     data:[{"ID":8,
            "Title":"Test Title",
            "Author":"Test Author",
            "Price":"18.00",
            "Edition":"1st",
            "Condition":"Good",
            "UploadDate":"2012-07-28 07:25:56.0"
            },     
          {"ID":9,
           "Title":"Test Title",
           "Author":"Test Author",
           "Price":"18.000000000000",
           "Edition":"1st",
           "Condition":"Good",
           "UploadDate":"2012-07-28 07:27:06.0"
          }
          ]
}
```

My question is, what is the most efficient way to grab all of the data from the 'data' array and use it to create either an NSArray or NSDictionary? Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Well if you are already using a framework shouldnt the framework take care of that for you?

Comment: Which framework are you using?

Comment: The JSON framework from Stig Brauatest. Could you give an example perhaps? Thanks.

Comment: @TimStullich: The posted data is not valid JSON data. Just try it in [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/). All keys ("count" and "data" in your case) must be quoted.

Comment: Thanks, for that. I fixed those errors.

Answer (score 0):

I use RestKit for JSON parsing. It has all you need to fetch the json from a server, translate it into a dictionary, and from there into an object that you can work with. That might be more than you dared to wish for, but it works like a charm. Check out https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from iOS5 a json parser has been integrated as a SDK native component see the following link http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5. 
You will create a NSDictionary with 2 keys "count" and "data" and then you will get the NSArray using objectForKey with the "data" key.